# the unsupervised neural network to solve a static Schrödinger equation

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, physics, tensorflow-quantum

I want to reproduce the results of the paper:

*Neural-network-based multistate solver for a static Schrödinger equation*, Hong Li, Qilong Zhai, and Jeff Z. Y. Chen, Phys. Rev. A 103, 032405 – Published 8 March 2021.

This is the deep NN used in the paper:
[image]

I tried to simple harmonic oscillator, the input is the *x*-coordinate value, the output is *N*+1 wave function ɸ*<sub>n</sub>(x)*, *N* is the main quantum number.

The loss function,

[image: loss function]

contains 3 parts: total energy, orthogonal normalization,

[image: orthogonal normalization]

L2 regularization,

[image: L2 regularization]

This is my code (considering total energy only):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Constants
hbar = tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
m = tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
omega = tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float32)

# Potential energy function
def potential_energy(x):
    return 0.5 * m * omega ** 2 * x ** 2

# Kinetic energy term
def kinetic_energy_term(psi, x):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch(x)
        dpsi_dx = tape.gradient(psi, x)
    d2psi_dx2 = tape.gradient(dpsi_dx, x)
    del tape  # Delete the tape after using it
    return -0.5 * hbar ** 2 / m * d2psi_dx2

# Expected energy function
def expected_energy(x, psi_n):
    ke = kinetic_energy_term(psi_n, x)
    pe = potential_energy(x)
    hamiltonian_psi = ke + pe * psi_n
    numerator = tf.reduce_sum(psi_n * hamiltonian_psi)
    denominator = tf.reduce_sum(psi_n * psi_n)
    return numerator / denominator

# Custom loss function
def unsupervised_loss(x, y_pred):
    energies = [expected_energy(x, y_pred[:, i:i + 1]) for i in range(y_pred.shape[-1])]
    energies=tf.convert_to_tensor(energies,dtype=tf.float32)
    energy_sum = tf.reduce_sum(energies)
    return energy_sum

# Neural network model
N = 10  # Number of quantum states
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(N, activation='linear')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: unsupervised_loss(y_true, y_pred))

# Training data
x_train = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000).reshape(-1, 1)
x_train_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train, dtype=tf.float32)
# %%
# Train the model
history = model.fit(x_train_tensor, x_train_tensor, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\software\work\python\anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-62-c0c5a991e6f1>", line 2, in <module>
    history = model.fit(x_train_tensor, x_train_tensor, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
  File "D:\software\work\python\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filendq0th2a.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filea5lnci17.py", line 5, in <lambda>
    tf__lam = (lambda y_true, y_pred: ag__.with_function_scope((lambda lscope: ag__.converted_call(unsupervised_loss, (y_true, y_pred), None, lscope)), 'lscope', ag__.STD))
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filea5lnci17.py", line 5, in <lambda>
    tf__lam = (lambda y_true, y_pred: ag__.with_function_scope((lambda lscope: ag__.converted_call(unsupervised_loss, (y_true, y_pred), None, lscope)), 'lscope', ag__.STD))
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filedrz1d0_q.py", line 10, in tf__unsupervised_loss
    energies = [ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(expected_energy), (ag__.ld(x), ag__.ld(y_pred)[:, ag__.ld(i):(ag__.ld(i) + 1)]), None, fscope) for i in ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(range), (ag__.ld(y_pred).shape[(- 1)],), None, fscope)]
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filedrz1d0_q.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    energies = [ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(expected_energy), (ag__.ld(x), ag__.ld(y_pred)[:, ag__.ld(i):(ag__.ld(i) + 1)]), None, fscope) for i in ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(range), (ag__.ld(y_pred).shape[(- 1)],), None, fscope)]
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file40wmfh26.py", line 10, in tf__expected_energy
    ke = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(kinetic_energy_term), (ag__.ld(psi_n), ag__.ld(x)), None, fscope)
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filemre1bw7b.py", line 13, in tf__kinetic_energy_term
    d2psi_dx2 = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tape).gradient, (ag__.ld(dpsi_dx), ag__.ld(x)), None, fscope)
TypeError: in user code:
    File "D:\software\work\python\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "<ipython-input-61-b273cbda69ea>", line 46, in None  *
        lambda y_true, y_pred: unsupervised_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    File "<ipython-input-61-b273cbda69ea>", line 33, in unsupervised_loss  *
        energies = [expected_energy(x, y_pred[:, i:i + 1]) for i in range(y_pred.shape[-1])]
    File "<ipython-input-50-7a5ddb0aa6ce>", line 24, in expected_energy  *
        ke = kinetic_energy_term(psi_n, x)
    File "<ipython-input-50-7a5ddb0aa6ce>", line 18, in kinetic_energy_term  *
        d2psi_dx2 = tape.gradient(dpsi_dx, x)
    TypeError: Argument `target` should be a list or nested structure of Tensors, Variables or CompositeTensors to be differentiated, but received None.
```

How to fix the error?